# dotcms community edition capability

Tags: dotcms

I am working on developing a weksite using a Java based CMS and had a close look at dotCMS community edition.
The website will initially hold some 500-600 pages, with good seo integration, performance, search capability. The pages will have images but no videos.
I want to run the site with dotcms community edition for a year or so and then upgrade to a licensed edition.
Can anybody please suggest if dotcms community edition can help build & run the site covering my above requirements.
Any pointers in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the community edition does not support integrated search (the licensed edition uses elastic search), so you'll have to add third party search. All the other requirements are not a problem. I've build many many sites with dotCMS and I have never had a problem with those aspects of the CMS.

To figure out what is in and what is out, check out this list: http://dotcms.com/explore/editions/

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Koenpeters, when we have a CE site on dotCMS we use Google custom search that we use, and then we have a plugin that feeds GCS a feed of all pages to index for searching...